# How to bind data from inputCheckboxGroup in Play Framework 2.3.8?

Tags: java, forms, playframework

I have such a view:

```
@(translationForm: play.data.Form[Translation])

@import helper._

@form(routes.Translate.index()) {

    @inputCheckboxGroup(
        translationForm("languages"),
        options = Seq("German" -> "German", "Spanish" -> "Spanish"))

}
```

How do I bind selected languages into Translate model?

How do I validate that at least one language is selected?

What should be in the controller and how the model should look like?

I find Play Framework 2.3 documentation extremely sparse, this is the only unhelpful [bit](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.inputCheckboxGroup$) which I found... No full examples at all...

I asked related question on [how to persist a collection of Strings in Play Framework 2.3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059787/how-to-persist-a-collection-of-strings-in-play-framework-2-3-8).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you can serve this code.

```
@(translationForm: play.data.Form[Translation])

@import helper._

@form(routes.Translate.index()) {

@inputCheckboxGroup(translationForm("languages"),
    options = helper.options(Languages.forSelect()),
    'class -> "checkbox")

}
```

in your model where you can have a method that will provide all languages

example:   `Languages.forSelect()`